Javascript Document.evalute failing with 'name()' in XPath
I am attempting to use the Javascript Document evaluate function with valid XPath that uses the name() / local-name() function but am consistently getting the following error in Jfiddle:
The string '/foods/*[position()=1</a>/local-name()' is not a valid XPath expression

It is unclear how or why the </a> fragment is introduced
Sample code is as follows:
const xml = "<foods><meat>chicken</meat><fruit>orange</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit><fruit>banana</fruit></foods>";

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'application/xml');

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++ ){
const xpath = `/foods/*[position()=${i+1}]`;
const xpathValue = document.evaluate(
  xpath,
  doc,
  null,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
  null
);
const xpathName = document.evaluate(
  `${xpath}/local-name()`,
  doc,
  null,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
  null
);

console.log(`${xpathName.stringValue} = ${xpathValue.stringValue}`);
}

The XPath evalutaing the value works fine, just not the node name. Any assistance would be appreciated.

That last step with a function call is allowed in XPath 2 and later but not version 1, use SaxonJS if you need the latest XPath version with Javascript.

Or in XPath 1, select a node and then call name on that node e.g. name(/*/*[position()=2])

You can use XPath 3.1 with SaxonJS 2:


const xml = "<foods><meat>chicken</meat><fruit>orange</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit><fruit>banana</fruit></foods>";

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'application/xml');

const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`/foods/*/(name() || ' = ' || string())`, doc);

console.log(result);
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/SaxonJS-2.6/SaxonJS2.js"></script>




Thanks @Martin Honnen - working code
onst xml = "<foods><meat>chicken</meat><fruit>orange</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit><fruit>banana</fruit></foods>";

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'application/xml');

for ( var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++ ){
const xpath = `/foods/*[position()=${i+1}]`;
const xpathValue = doc.evaluate(
  xpath,
  doc,
  null,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
  null
);
let resolver = function () { return "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";}
const xpath2 = `name(/foods/*[position()=${i+1}])`;
console.log(xpath2);
const xpathName = doc.evaluate(
  xpath2,
  doc,
  resolver,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
  null
);

console.log(`${xpathName.stringValue} = ${xpathValue.stringValue}`);
}



It might be better to first select and process e.g. /foods/*[position() <= 4] and then to pass each node as the context node on e.g. string() and name() evaluations. Selecting the element nodes twice seems unnecessary. Of course it won't matter for the short sample.
